# Msdeploy: Getting a list of files affected by checksum comparison

Tags: tfs, msbuild, msdeploy

I have a custom .proj file in a large web project that calling msdeploy with -useChecksum option to update only modified files in my staging environment and it works fine. But I can't use msdeploy on my production environment, so, I need to make a .zip package to another team with the modified files to a manual deployment in that ambient.

My question is: can I get a list of files modified by msdeploy in your deployment process? With this I can automatically make a .zip with the same structure and files that has been modified in a build...

Some advices?

Answer (score 0):

For second part , i suggest you to use `InvokeProcess activity` and call `Zip Tool` in order to compress.
this custom activity must be integrated to your build definition (Workflow)

Comment: But how do I know which files were affected in the deployment process (updated or created)?

Comment: You can FileInfo class in order to access properties of file

Comment: Sorry, Aghilas, but I can figure out that I can get infos about a file, but I need to know which file is that. I need to know which files were affected by MSDeploy checksum... I need a list with the names of files that were created or updated by MSDeploy, and this list is what I trying to recover.... I may not have understood your answer, if you guess this is the case, can I ask you to post a sample code to me? Thanks

Comment: after you have deployed your files, read propecties of your files in deployed repository,, sorry i can't post in this moment